# Could not find rails-assets-fontawesome-4.2.0 in any of the sources error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundle

When I `git push` to heroku, I got a error `Could not find rails-assets-fontawesome-4.2.0 in any of the sources error.

To solve the problem I `bundle update` and push it again, but error remains.

I thought maybe the version is not available somehow. I searched in `rubygems.org`.

https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=rails-assets-fontawesome

But the gem is not exist.

Last time I could deploy without problem.

Probably the error comes up because of ruby versions automatic update.

```
remote:        Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
remote:        Old: ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        New: ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-linux]
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-font-awesome', '~> 4.3.0'
end
```

Also, look int to [this](https://github.com/rails-assets/rails-assets/issues/272)

Comment: Thanks, I could install the gem. Short notice for someone who come to here by google. I also need to change `@import "fontawesome";` to `@import "font-awesome";`.